# Codeship Custom Script Deployment to GAE: "python2: command not found"

Tags: google-app-engine, codeship

I've followed Codeship's [custom script](https://documentation.codeship.com/basic/continuous-deployment/deployment-with-custom-scripts/) deployment pipeline setup but reached trouble with the following error when trying to deploy to Google App Engine:

`pyenv: python2: command not found`

Here are screenshots of my codeship setup commands:
[image: setup commands]
The deployment pipeline setup:
[image: codeship GAE custom deployment pipeline]

and the Codeship console output:
[image: codeship console error]

Any ideas why it thinks I'm on python2?

Comment: So I found this in the Codeship [documentation](https://documentation.codeship.com/basic/languages-frameworks/python/#versions-and-setup) it seems that there is an enviroment issue with pyenv.

Have a look at this github [thread](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1159) they were having the same error as you.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to reach CodeShip support is by emailing support@codeship.com - You'll need to set the python version to 2.7 before the deploy steps in order to use this deploy script.

We can continue to work on the ticket created with support - but I wanted to be sure to answer here for any other users. :)

Answer (score 0):

Combining the answers from @Michelle and @eespinola, I had to change from:

`pyenv local 3.7`

to:

`pyenv global 2.7 3.7`

in the setup commands